# Pass args and kwargs into reverse Django

Tags: python, django

I have a link that is set up as follows: `page/<key>` where key is a randomly generated key, that is setup here:

```
reverse('page', args=(key,))
```

However, I want to also pass data into the `page/<key>` endpoint. However, if I add another variable into args here: `reverse('page', args=(key, more_data))` then it gets messed up as it tries to open a url at: `page/<key>/<more_data>`

Furthermore, django doesn't allow args and kwargs in one reverse call. How would I pass data in then? Thanks!

Comment: You can not "pass data". `reverse(..)` will simply calculate an URL, this is just a string, so there is no other way than to encode the data in the URL.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I see, but the way I am doing this is generating a random url for someone to click on, so don't want to redirect. Would I have to store it in my db? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @RahulRentash can you update your question to expand more on what you're trying to accomplish? (e.g. "I'm trying to get <this workflow> to work, but this method I've been trying to do isn't working". You have the second part, but not much of the first part; there's some detail in comments below, but there are still a few unclear things) The more information you provide, the better we can help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @willem-van-onsem commented `reverse` is just builds the url, you need to redirect to it, you can put something like this in your view:

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('page', kwargs={'key': 'value'}))`

check out the docs about this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/

Comment: I see, but the way I am doing this is generating a random url for someone to click on, so don't want to redirect. Would I have to store it in my db? Or is there a better way?

Comment: let's say you have a function `generate_key` the generates a random key, you can generate the url like so `reverse('page', kwargs={'key': generate_key()})`
how to pass that url to the user depends on your use case

Comment: I understand, but use this for example: I have an input field that has a recipients email, a dropdown for favorite color, and a submit button. Now, when the submit button is pressed, I want to generate this random url and email it to them. But I want the background color of the random link page to be their favorite color. How would I pass in  that data without putting it in the url? Does this make sense?

Comment: for the url generating part I think I answered your question, for url background color you simply make it a variable in your email template and pass the value from the view
NOTE: `page` is the name of the url not what appears in the url string

Comment: But how do I pass the color value from the email template to the random generated link?

Comment: you're gonna pass both the color and the url string to the template

Comment: Sorry, I am new to django and not following. Can you show me how you would do this in code? Thanks.

Comment: Update the question by providing more details( urls, views...) so that I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the kwargs you're trying to send are used on that page to help determine what things to render/how to render them, and aren't used as identifiers or to help with url signing.

If that's the case, let's go with your background color example posted in the comments of another answer. There are a bunch of different ways to actually use the data you get on the destination page to display the color, so I'll consider that out of scope. If you're doing this with javascript, [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is what you'll want to look into.

The standard way to pass data along like this is to use url query parameters (the `?key=value` things you sometimes see in a url).

Here's how you'd generate the url you send via email using python and django:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from django.urls import reverse

url_params = {"background_color": "#000000"}
url = reverse("page", kwargs={"key": generate_key()}) + f"?{urlencode(url_params)}"
```

If you want to make the data you're sending a bit less obvious, you can encode the url params dictionary in base64 and send that along as a "settings" param that you can decode and use in javascript.

Comment: I am assuming you meant to put url_params in the urlencode method... is that the case?